# Filtering text file data as columns in pyspark rdd and dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have data like below:

```
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Image sheets containing Buddy passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
 software like

1   long title 1
2 long title 2
3 long title 3
4 long title 4
5 long title 5
6 long title 6
7 long title 7
8 long title 8
9 long title 9
10 long title 10
11 long title 11
12 long title 12
13 long title 13
14 long title 14
15 long title 15
16 long title 16
17 long title 17
18 long title 18
19 long title 19
20 long title 20
```

Now, while loading this text file I have to exclude junk data i.e paragraph and have to include data starting from `long title 1` i.e columnar data. I am using RDD but not able to load it correctly. Once data in RDD is populated correctly then I can convert it to dataframe. Below is my code:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf


sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
load_data=sc.textFile("E://long_sample.txt").filter(lambda x : "title")
load_data.foreach(print())
```

Even though I am trying to filter it on "`title`" I am still getting the entire data which is not correct. Please help me to sort it out. There is no error being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> try this in Pyspark:

```
>>> load_data=sc.textFile("file:///home/mahesh/Downloads/line_text.txt")
```

filter data using IN statement and for creating data frame from existing RDD

```
>>> load_data.filter(lambda x: "title" in x).map(lambda x:(x.split(" ")[0],x.split(" ")[1]+" " + x.split(" ")[2],x.split(" ")[3] )).toDF(["Id","Name","Number"])

>>> df.show()
+---+----------+------+
| Id|      Name|Number|
+---+----------+------+
|  1|long title|     1|
|  2|long title|     2|
|  3|long title|     3|
|  4|long title|     4|
|  5|long title|     5|
|  6|long title|     6|
|  7|long title|     7|
|  8|long title|     8|
|  9|long title|     9|
| 10|long title|    10|
| 11|long title|    11|
| 12|long title|    12|
| 13|long title|    13|
| 14|long title|    14|
| 15|long title|    15|
| 16|long title|    16|
| 17|long title|    17|
| 18|long title|    18|
| 19|long title|    19|
| 20|long title|    20|
+---+----------+------+
```

let me know if you need more help on the same.

Comment: Yeah, thanks it worked. but how do I create a dataframe out of this RDD. i tried spark.createDataFrame but it didn't work

Comment: updated the answer have a look if its satisfy your requirement don't forget to accept and upvote the answer

Comment: Actually I want 3 columns out of this RDD. Suppose ID, Name(data like "Long title")and Number. So, Could you please modify for these 3 columns?

Comment: on which basis you want to split your RDD? because if you want to split on the basis of space then space is also between string.

Comment: For the first record, you can ignore the extra space. I have removed extra space and aligned it according to the other records.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way using `rlike` and regular expressions through dataframe API:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ('It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Image sheets containing Buddy passages, and more recently with desktop publishing'),
  ('software like'),
  ('1   long title 1'),
  ('2 long title 2'),
  ('3 long title 3'),
  ('4 long title 4'),
  ('5 long title 5'),
  ('6 long title 6'),
  ('7 long title 7'),
  ('8 long title 8'),
  ('9 long title 9'),
  ('10 long title 10'),
  ('11 long title 11'),
  ('12 long title 12')
], StringType())

df.where(f.col("value").rlike("\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\d+")).show(100, False)

# +----------------+
# |           value|
# +----------------+
# |1   long title 1|
# |  2 long title 2|
# |  3 long title 3|
# |  4 long title 4|
# |  5 long title 5|
# |  6 long title 6|
# |  7 long title 7|
# |  8 long title 8|
# |  9 long title 9|
# |10 long title 10|
# |11 long title 11|
# |12 long title 12|
# +----------------+
```

rlike here will identify the rows for which there is a match with the regex `\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\d+`. Here is an explanation for the regex:

- \d+: one or more digits
- \s+: followed by one or more spaces
- \w+: followed by one or more lower case letters
- \s+: followed by one or more spaces
- .....

If you are sure that the words long and title are always present you can modify the regex to: `\d+\s+long\s+title\s+\d+`.

**UPDATE:**

In order to split your dataset into a new dataset with columns `id, name, number` use select and split as next:

```
df.where(df["value"].rlike("\d+\s+long\s+title\s+\d+")) \
  .select(
          f.split(df["value"], "\s+").getItem(0).alias("id"),
          f.concat(f.split(df["value"], "\s+").getItem(1), f.split(df["value"], "\s+").getItem(2)).alias("name"),
          f.split(df["value"], "\s+").getItem(3).alias("number")
  ).show()

# +---+---------+------+
# | id|     name|number|
# +---+---------+------+
# |  1|longtitle|     1|
# |  2|longtitle|     2|
# |  3|longtitle|     3|
# |  4|longtitle|     4|
# |  5|longtitle|     5|
# |  6|longtitle|     6|
# |  7|longtitle|     7|
# |  8|longtitle|     8|
# |  9|longtitle|     9|
# | 10|longtitle|    10|
# | 11|longtitle|    11|
# | 12|longtitle|    12|
# +---+---------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Alexandros. But, here the data provided is very short. So, I can't pass the entire data createDataFrame method since it won't be feasible and I want 3 columns out of this data(ID,NAME,NUMBER). "long title" data will be assigned to NAME column. So, could you please modify it?

Comment: Hi @RushHour, yes here the data is a sample data, in a real world you would do something like `spark.read.text(YOUR_PATH)` to read the text file

Comment: Hi again, I updated the answer with the new functionality which produces a new dataset with cols `id, name, number`

Comment: yes both solutions are very similar and I dont think there is a significant difference on performance as well. So it depends on you which style and API prefer mostly RDD or dataframes :)

Answer (score 0):

Please also try with [regexp_extract](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) all at once. Later you can remove blank lines.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df=spark.read.text('test.txt')

df.select(F.regexp_extract('value', r'(^\d+)\s+(.*)\s+(\d+$)', 1).alias('id')
    ,F.regexp_extract('value',r'(^\d+)\s+(.*)\s+(\d+$)',2).alias('name')
    ,F.regexp_extract('value', r'(^\d+)\s+(.*)\s+(\d+$)', 3).alias('number')
    ).show()
```